# REGEX Select From Where Word NOT Found Difficulty

Tags: regex, regex-group

I need a regex to match phishing email names, where a specific name or word is NOT found.

For example...

```
John Smith (notmyemail@sodifh.com)
John Smith (notmyemail@SODI.com)
John Smith (jsmit34@gmail.com)
John Smith (myRealEmail@mymail.com)
```

Where the bottom email is the only legit email, and needs to be ignored.

I have tried similar to:

```
^(J|j)ohn.(S|s)mith.*\@^((?i)\bmymail\.com\b)*$
```

But this fails to select the 3 bad emails.
Also tried similar to:

```
^(J|j)ohn.(S|s)mith.*@gmail\.com
```

but this method only removes the Gmail one.

How can I properly pattern match to remove all bad emails regardless of letter case, and to only allow one domain (in this case mymail.com) and no others?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this regex with a negative look ahead condition

```bash
^[jJ]ohn.[sS]mith[^@]*@(?!mymail\.com).+
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/RAIuzn/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `[jJ]ohn`: Match `John` or `john`
- `.`: Match any character
- `[sS]mith[`: Match `Smith` or `smith`
- `[^@]*`: Match 0 or kore of any character except `@`
- `@`: Match a `@`
- `(?!mymail\.com)`: Negative lookahead to fail the match if we have `mymail.com` is at next position
- `.+`: Match 1+ of any character